# NextJS logo meta data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo

In NextJS, in the layout.ts, there is this metadata:

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'UpWhere Global Tapestry',
  description: 'Crafting tales from each nook and cranny.',
}
```

How can I include a logo image in the metadata?

Comment: export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'UpWhere Global Tapestry',
  description: 'Crafting tales from each nook and cranny.', icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        media: "(prefers-color-scheme: light)",
        url: "/images/favicon-light.png",
        href: "/images/favicon-light.png",
      }]},
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
```

it has this field

```
 icons?: null | IconURL | Array<Icon> | Icons;
```

this is the only field you pass image link.